# Saving multiple classes on raster dataset as individual shapefiles using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, fields-attributes, convert

I have this raster dataset (.tif) of land use cover. There are 22 individual classes in total.

Is there any way I can separate these classes and convert them each into individual shapefiles?

I want to eventually input each of these habitat classes separately into a model.

I tried to [Select By Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm), but since it is not a feature class, ArcMap did not allow me to proceed. I tried to convert the file from a raster to a shapefile, but I also did not manage.

Does anyone have any advice?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: take a look at the [Raster to Polygon](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool. Once it is a vector layer (polygon) you can use select by attributes.

Comment: Thanks! Does it normally take a long time to process (It's a 9GB file)?

Comment: Depending how much RAM you have, you could save the conversion [in_memory](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) which would significantly speed up the processing. But the result does not persist once you close ArcMap.

Comment: Raster to polygon followed by split by attributes.